# Ошибка document.querySelector(...) is null

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="price"]').addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});

document.querySelector('.create').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.form').innerHTML = '<input name="price" value="100">';
});
```

```html
<form class="form"></form><span class="create">Создать поле</span>
```

Comment: В тот момент когда Вы добавляете ивент лиснер для элемента `input[name="price"]` его не существует, какого поведения Вы ожидали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.create').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.form').innerHTML = '<input name="price" value="100">';
  document.querySelector('.form input[name="price"]').addEventListener('input', e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
}, {once: true});
```

```html
<form class="form"></form><span class="create">Создать поле</span>
```